# Multi-index storing complex types

Tags: multi-index

Is it possible to make a multi-instance table of a struct Base with a couple of virtual methods, and then store entries of derived classes and have it be able to differentiate? So ie:

```
struct animal {
  virtual void make_noise();
}

struct dog : animal {
  void make_noise() { print "woof!"; }
}

multi_index<N(animals), animal> animals;
```

and then somehow store an entry that would somehow know how to "woof!" upon retrival?

Or perhaps store a type with a whole other type as field which would implicitly have the correct method so:

```
struct container {
  animal myanimal
}

dog mydog;  
container c;
c.animal = mydog;

multi_index<N(animals), container> animals;

animals.emplace(get_self(), [](auto a) {
  a.animal = c.animal;
});
```

Or are the fields of a multi-index table limited to basic types such as string, uint16_t etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The EOS multi-index table is based on [Boost multi-index containers](https://www.boost.org/doc/). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399740/how-to-create-boost-multi-index-key-to-a-member-of-member) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538430/pointer-to-member-variable-in-nested-struct) it doesn't seem possible to store classes directly as fields, but it seems possible to manage class inheritance with proper indexing and handlers.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know about storing pointers? It seems like you can with boost::multi-index but I wonder how it would work with abi files etc

Comment: Having experimented a bit it doesn't seem you can.